# Can't get to work css-borders in mpdf

Tags: php, css, mpdf

i'm trying to export a data-table with mpdf and cannot get to work css-borders, i already tried a lot of things...

I also tried to apply borders for testing on a heading in this simple example:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        @media(print)
        {
            h1
            {
                font-size: 16px;
                box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
            }

            table
            {
                width: 100%;
                font-size: 13px;
                border: none;
            }

            td
            {
                border: 1px black solid;
                box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
            }
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Headline
        </h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>blabla</td>
                <td>blabla</td>
                <td>blabla</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
$content = ob_get_clean();
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<div class="footer"><span class="pagenum">Seite: {PAGENO} / {nbpg}</span></div>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf->Output();
```

I also tried to put the css into a external stylesheet or apply it inline, but no success..
(Latest mpdf version installed via Composer)
The strange thing tough is that the font-size and background-styles are being applied o.O

Is there anything i missed?

Update:
I've updated the code, tried to apply box-shadows too, they are applied to the h1, but not the td-elements.. also it seems not a really clean solution for tables...

Comment: Try working with box-shadows instead of borders. Just use one `WriteHTML` width styles included inside the `<html>`. & you should be able to echo $content;exit; before generating the pdf to save some time when test by viewing in your browser instead of building the pdf each time you test and edit.

Comment: Thanks for your response, well, the borders and box-shadows are working flawlessly when rendered to the browser instead of the pdf..
Strange thing is, that the box-shadow is applied correctly to the h1, but not the td-elements...  
I've also updated the code inside the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct CSS `border` definition as per specificaton is `<br-width> || <br-style> || <color>`

Code works as expected in mPDF when the CSS definition is

```
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Answer (score 1):

So far as I am dropping some lines, there is still something wrong with MPDF when dealing with table borders.
When you style `<td>` and add border there, what you can see in the output is just `border left` and `border right`, and **no** `border top` and `border down`. For me, so as to bypass the problem, I styled both `<tr>` and `<td>` to get all the borders, that is the top, bottom, right, and left borders. I just shared my solution in case someone would find it useful.

```
table td, table th, table tr {
border: 1px solid #c9c9c9 !important
}
```